# how to handle if condition inside another if condition not working has excepted in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have implemented this condition but the result is not expected. When I click first time its working properly but when I switch back and forth it not working. when i click "yes" its shows "no" selection result and sometimes nothing.

```
Handler(){
  if (document.getElementById("Yes").checked) {
    this.setState({
      isHiddenYes: !this.state.isHiddenYes
    });
    console.log("hello yes");
  } else {
    this.setState({
      isHiddenNo: !this.state.isHiddenNo
    });
    console.log("hello no");
  }
};

<div className="textBlock" onChange={this.Handler}>

<div><input type="radio" name="List" id="Yes" value="Yes" required />Yes</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="List" id="No" value="No" />No</div>

{
(this.state.isHiddenYes) ?
(
<div className="subtitle1">
    <div className="input">
        <div><input type="radio" name="L1" id="1" value="1" required />1</div>

        <div><input type="radio" name="L1" id="2" value="2" />2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div className="subtitle2">
    <div className="input">
        <div><input type="radio" name="R1" id="1" value="3" required />3</div>

        <div><input type="radio" name="R1" id="2" value="4" />4</div>
    </div>
</div>) :
''
}

{
(this.state.isHiddenNo) ?
(<div className="No">
    <div className="inputIcon" onClick={this.Onclick}>

        <input className="subtitle3" type="text" />
    </div>
    {
    (this.state.isHiddenX) ?
    (<div className="radio">
        <fieldset>
            <div><input type="radio" name="LR1" id="1" value="1" required />1</div>

            <div><input type="radio" name="LR1" id="2" value="2" />2</div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>) : ''
    }
    <div className="inputIcon" onClick={this.Onclick}>

        <input className="subtitle4" type="text" />

    </div>
    {
    (this.state.isHiddenY) ?
    (<div className="Radio">
        <fieldset>
            <div><input type="radio" name="LR2" id="3" required />3</div>

            <div><input type="radio" name="LR2" id="4" />4</div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>) : ''
    }
</div>)
: ''
}
</div>
```

Not sure whether I am doing it right way.

Basically When I click Yes ==> I need to show some piece of code but when I click No ==> need to show different piece of code. In my case when i click first time it's working fine but going back and forth on Yes and No selections it is not working properly.

errors:1.) sometimes It shows No piece of code on YES 
2.) sometimes blanks nothing is showing
3.) When I click No it shows the right code (when I select anyone of them ) --> it takes me to Yes piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont prefer to use `onChange` method for this kind of things, its best if you use `onClick` method for this thing. But in the example below i used `onChange` method.

### Try playing with this code I hope you will understand:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const { Fragment } = React;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super();
    this.state = {
      isHiddenYes: true,
      isHiddenNo: true,
      isHiddenX: false,
      isHiddenY: false,
    }
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
  }


  handler() {
    if (document.getElementById('Yes').checked) {
      this.setState({
        isHiddenYes: !this.state.isHiddenYes
      });
      console.log("hello yes");
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isHiddenNo: !this.state.isHiddenNo
      }); console.log("hello no");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="textBlock" onChange={this.handler} >
            <div><input type="radio" name="List" id="Yes" value="Yes"  required/>Yes</div>
            <div><input type="radio" name="List" id="No" value="No" />No</div>

            {
              (this.state.isHiddenYes) ?
                (
                  <Fragment>
                    <div className="subtitle1">
                      <div className="input">
                        <div><input type="radio" name="L1" id="1" value="1"  required/>1</div>

                        <div><input type="radio" name="L1" id="2" value="2" />2</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="subtitle2">
                      <div className="input"><div><input type="radio" name="R1" id="1" value="3"  required/>3</div>

                      <div><input type="radio" name="R1" id="2" value="4"/>4</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </Fragment>
                  ) :
                ''
            }

            {
              (this.state.isHiddenNo) ?
                (
                <div className="No">
                  <div className="inputIcon" onClick={this.Onclick}>
                    <input className="subtitle3" type="text"/>
                  </div>
                  {this.state.isHiddenX ?
                      (
                      <div className="radio">
                        <fieldset>
                          <div><input type="radio" name="LR1" id="1" value="1"  required/>1</div>
                          <div><input type="radio" name="LR1" id="2" value="2" />2</div>
                        </fieldset>
                      </div>
                      ) : ''
                  }
                  <div className="inputIcon" onClick={this.Onclick}>

                    <input className="subtitle4" type="text"/>

                  </div>
                  {this.state.isHiddenY ?
                      (<div className="Radio">
                        <fieldset>
                          <div><input type="radio" name="LR2" id="3"  required/>3</div>
                          <div><input type="radio" name="LR2" id="4"  />4</div>
                        </fieldset>
                      </div>
                      ) : ''
                  }
                </div>
                )
              : ''
            }
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

### UPDATE

change your handler like this:

```
handler() {
    if (document.getElementById('Yes').checked) {
      this.setState({
        isHiddenYes: !this.state.isHiddenYes,
        isHiddenNo: false,
      });
      console.log("hello yes");
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isHiddenNo: !this.state.isHiddenNo,
        isHiddenYes: false
      }); console.log("hello no");
    }
```

change your constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) { 
    super();
    this.state = {
      isHiddenYes: false,
      isHiddenNo: false,
      isHiddenX: false,
      isHiddenY: false,
    }
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: It's not working still have issue with proper rendering after initial clicks

Comment: thanks it works, but manipulating from DOM is not recommended in react has @kyaw said.

Comment: That is true, we don't manipulate DOM in React, What I can suggest to you is to read more on React docs. They provide everything you want there.

Answer (score 1):

you have to wrap JSX elements in one enclosing tag

**like this**

```
  {true ? (
    <div>
      <div> </div>
      <div> </div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    ""
  )}
```

**can not be like this**

```
  {true ? (
      <div> </div>
      <div> </div>
  ) : (
    ""
  )}
```

**UPDATE**

it's not recommended to manipulate DOM directly, React is not for that

**instead of this**

```
Handler(){
  if (document.getElementById("Yes").checked) {
    this.setState({
      isHiddenYes: !this.state.isHiddenYes
    });
    console.log("hello yes");
  } else {
    this.setState({
      isHiddenNo: !this.state.isHiddenNo
    });
    console.log("hello no");
  }
};
```

**you can do like this**

```
  onRadioButtonChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    console.log(value);
    if (value === "Yes") {
      this.setState({
        isHidden: true
      });
      console.log("hello yes");
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isHidden: false
      });
      console.log("hello no");
    }
  };
```

and add `onRadioButtonChange` to your radio element 
**like this**

```
  <div>
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={this.onRadioButtonChange}
        type="radio"
        name="List"
        value="Yes"
        required
      />Yes
    </div>
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={this.onRadioButtonChange}
        type="radio"
        name="List"
        value="No"
      />No
    </div>
    {this.state.isHidden ? (
      <h1>Hidden Yes Element</h1>
    ) : (
      <h1>Hidden No Element</h1>
    )}
  </div>
```

here your code with right format https://codesandbox.io/embed/6v2p1wl25k

Comment: I am doing the way you suggested only.. Did't added that in sample code here

Comment: @Poosapati I've update the answer and code, can you try the link again.

Comment: thanks for the help. but I have a weird prblm the selection of radio button is not visible

Comment: @Poosapati i appreciate to help but i need to know what you try to archive, please write down your code in https://codesandbox.io as simple as you can and explain what do you wanna to do.

Comment: i could't share the code. basically I need to render either Yes or No fields value and store it in database.

Comment: @Poosapati ok, i think the database thing is out of the question, and i think we already answer your question about **handle-if-condition ...**, please click accept one of the answers that help you.

Comment: no you haven’t accepted the answer, accept and upvote are different

Answer (score 0):

The event `onChange={this.Handler}` should be at both inputs `type="radio" name="List"` not at the `div`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I tried has you suggested but the result is same what I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous. You need to log it this way:

```
this.setState({ isHiddenYes: !this.state.isHiddenYes },
    () => { console.log(`isHiddenYes changed to ${this.state.isHiddenYes}`)} );
```

Also, you can evaluate your return based on true and false only by just having isHidden as your state rather than calling multiple setState for Yes and No.

For e.g:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() { 
    super();
    this.state = {
      isHidden: true
    }

    /*some code logic*/

    return (

    isHidden ? <div>'This is True'</div>
    : <div>'This is False'</div>

    )
```

or if you don't want to display anything unless clicked:

```
    return (

    isHidden ? <div>'This is True'</div>
    : !isHidden ? <div>'This is False'</div>
    : null

    )
```